# Can't boot Remix OS, system doesn't see the OS on the drive

Tags: linux, boot, operating-systems

I can't boot Remix OS from my hard drive because it can't find the OS:

> An operating system wasn't found. Try disconnecting any drives that don't contain an operating system.
>   Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart

[image: (Photo of the error)]

Is there a fix for this? I'm forced to use the Remix OS Player instead until this is resolved.

Comment: Fun Fact: This laptop screen is dirty because its a touchscreen so that's why it has fingerprints

Comment: Have you set the partition containing the OS or bootloader to active? See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3103656